# SQL Alchemy v2 is after_transaction_end needed for nested session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In [Setting Up a SQLAlchemy and Pytest Based Test Suite](https://aalvarez.me/posts/setting-up-a-sqlalchemy-and-pytest-based-test-suite/) (published May 2022 with SQLAlchemy v1), for the transactional testing, it uses the below code snippet.  Note I cleaned it up a bit for this post:

```py
# conftest.py

import pytest

# Import a session factory in our app code. Possibly created using
# `sessionmaker()`
from myapp.db import Session

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def session(connection):
    transaction = connection.begin()
    session = Session(bind=connection)
    session.begin_nested()

    @event.listens_for(session, "after_transaction_end")
    def restart_savepoint(db_session, ended_transaction):
        if ended_transaction.nested and not ended_transaction._parent.nested:
            session.expire_all()
            session.begin_nested()

    yield session

    Session.remove()
    transaction.rollback()
```

I am now working with SQLAlchemy v2 in November 2023, and have three questions around the `restart_savepoint` inner function:

- Can you explain the `ended_transaction.nested and not ended_transaction._parent.nested` logic?
- Is this `restart_savepoint` behavior still necessary with SQL Alchemy v2?
- Is the `Session(bind=connection)` still necessary with SQL Alchemy v2?

I am thinking the below is equally viable:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def session(connection):
    with Session() as session, session.begin(nested=True):
        yield session
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ended_transaction.nested and not ended_transaction._parent.nested`:

That logic is used to detect the end of a top-level nested transaction. Here is a breakdown:

- `ended_transaction.nested`: Checks if the transaction that just ended is nested.
- `not ended_transaction._parent.nested`: Makes sure its parent transaction is not nested.

Combined, this means the code inside the `if` block runs only when a top-level nested transaction ends, but not when a non-nested transaction or a sub-nested transaction ends.

---

Is `restart_savepoint` Necessary in SQLAlchemy v2?

I suspect not, considering it is removed in [commit d050193](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/commit/d050193daaa8d91371c759296f3304b8641c1976), named "fully implement future engine and remove legacy"

---

Is `Session(bind=connection)` Still Necessary?

In SQLAlchemy v2, explicitly binding a session to a connection is generally not required if you are using the context manager pattern (`with Session() as session`). The session will manage the connection lifecycle automatically. However, if you have specific requirements, like reusing an existing connection across multiple sessions, you may still need to bind manually.
You can still find it in [commit 6bf32f5](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/commit/6bf32f56e28d14f6ba15517dea34a87d37bbe644)

---

Your suggested code:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def session(connection):
    with Session() as session, session.begin(nested=True):
        yield session
```

That is a more concise and idiomatic way of handling sessions in SQLAlchemy v2. It takes advantage of context managers for handling session and transaction lifecycles, which is a recommended practice in SQLAlchemy v2. See [Session Basics](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/900d13acb4f19de955eb609dea52a755f0d11acb/doc/build/orm/session_basics.rst#L79) for details.